# pscp file transfer error output redirected to file

Tags: redirect, vbscript, output, pscp

I would like to transfer one file via pscp using wscript and this code just don't work.
It doesn't throw any error, but it won't transfer file or make output either.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Exec "C:\scripts\putty\pscp.exe -pw password C:\file_to_transfer.txt user@server.cz:/directory  2>> C:\Log_file.txt"
```

thanks for help....

Answer (score 0):

You need a shell for shell features (e.g. redirection). So prepend "%comspec% /c " to your command.

Do you know that .Exec allows to read the StdOut/StdErr of the called process?

Evidence:

```
>> f = "c:\temp\pscp.log"
>> c = "pscp -pw pword -ls user@host:/home"
>> set s = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>> WScript.Echo s.Run(c & " > " & f, 0, True)
>> WScript.Echo s.Run( "%comspec% /c " & c & " > " & f, 0, True)
>> WScript.Echo goFS.OpenTextFile(f).ReadAll()
>> WScript.Echo s.Exec(c).Stdout.ReadAll()
>>
1   <-- no shell/%comspec%, no luck
0   <-- it did not fail
Listing directory /home  <-- .Run did work with shell
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root         4096 Feb 22  2011 .
...

Listing directory /home <-- .Exec().Stdout.ReadAll() works
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root         4096 Feb 22  2011 .
...
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for me. Throw error on line 6 char 1 - required goFS object.

Comment: @user3493540 - it's *evidence* not 'ready to copy & paste code'. Please ask yourself what object has an .OpenTextFile method. Did you try the `%comspec% /c` addition?

Comment: This is my first task in scripting so I quite have no idea what I'm doing. I would be happy if I could just transfer that file over pscp for begining...